# What is a subdirect product?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lattice-orders, universal-algebra

I'm having trouble understanding what a [subdirect product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdirect_product) is.

Say $G$ is a subdirect product of $H=\prod H_i$ - this means that the homomorphisms $f_i:G\to H_i$ are surjective, which can be trivially accomplished as $f_i(g)=1$.

So isn't it the case that $G$ is a subdirect product of $H$ for all $G,H$?

Comment: I wonder if you really read the definition.

Comment: @Martin: I tried, but maybe I'm not understanding the term "subalgebra inclusion" (it doesn't bring up any relevant results in google). It seems to me a valid inclusion is $g\mapsto 1$, in which case the derived homomorphism is surjective for any projection.

Comment: You have a rather strange idea of what being surjective means.

Comment: I think the OP means that you could take each $H_i$ to be a trivial algebra for each $i$. Of course this doesn't work given the requirement that $G$ be a subalgebra of $\prod H_i$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$G$ has to be a [subalgebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subalgebra) of $H$. If $G$ is a subalgebra of $H$, then "subalgebra inclusion" refers to the mapping that identifies each element of $G$ with itself considered as an element of $H$. So for each pair $g, g' \in G$, if $g \not= g'$, there must be an $i$ with $f_i(g) \not= f_i(g')$.

For an example in the case of abelian groups, the group of integers can be viewed as a subdirect product of the groups of integers modulo $n$: $\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to the subgroup of the product $\prod_{n > 0}\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ comprising the elements of the form $(j + 1\mathbb{Z}, j + 2\mathbb{Z}, j + 3\mathbb{Z}, \ldots)$.

Comment: So if G is a subdirect product of H, can we say that G is isomorphic to a subalgebra of H?

Comment: Did you read the definition here? http://orion.math.iastate.edu/cliff/BurrisSanka.pdf  As Rob states, part of the definition is that G is already a subalgebra of H.  If you want to instead talk about a subdirect embedding of G into H, then yes, G would be isomorphic to a subalgebra of H.  When I was learning this stuff, I found Ross Willard's explanation of subdirect representations helpful. See page 4 of http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~rdwillar/documents/Publications/torino.pdf

Comment: @William: Thanks, those links are helpful. I came across this in the context of lattice-ordered groups, and don't know much about universal algebra.

Comment: @WilliamDeMeo The first link in your comment has expired. It would be great if you could replace it with one that works :)